# decile in ggplot (geom_bar) with a fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a data frame with three variables. Here is the `str()`

```
'data.frame':   282 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ stars  : num  1 3 3.5 2 3.5 3 3.5 3 3.5 3.5 ...
 $ is_open: chr  "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
```

Here is a small sample:

```
structure(list(stars = c(1, 3, 3.5, 2, 3.5), is_open = c("1", 
"0", "0", "1", "1")), .Names = c("stars", "is_open"), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to make a bar plot with `ggplot` of the variable `stars`in form of deciles with a fill for the variable `is_open`.

But I only get this version because I don´t know how to select the `deciles` and the `is_open` variable

```
test %>% select(stars) %>% quantile(na.rm = T, c(0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1)) %>% barplot()
```

But I only get this result. 
[image: 1]]

With ggplot it is not working:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = stars(na.rm = T, c(0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1)), fill = is_open)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") 

Error in stars(na.rm = T, c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, : 'x' must be a matrix or a data frame
```

Any idea how to integrate the `is_open` variable via `ggplot`? It should be look like this:

[image]

Comment: `stars()` is a function. That's not what you want. Best to make the data.frame you need and then plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the data.frame first (as Richard suggests). Then plot separately:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

test_quant <- test %>% 
  group_by(is_open) %>% 
  do(x = seq(0, 1, 0.1),
     quant = quantile(.$stars, seq(0, 1, 0.1))) %>% 
  unnest()

ggplot(test_quant, aes(as.factor(x), quant, fill = is_open)) + 
   geom_col(position = 'dodge')
```

[image]